# Find the order of U(36) using Euler ϕ−function, also find the order of 5 in U(36)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was wondering if anybody can look over my proof and see if I made any mistakes or if their is a simpilar way of solving this problem.

Find the order of U(36) using Euler ϕ−function, also find the
order of 5 in U(36)
Note: Must use Euler ϕ−function to complete the first job

[image]

I want to thank you ahead of time for take the time to assist me.

Comment: When you're stepping through powers like that, you can take the modulus at each step to simplify the calculation (if needed). So $5^3 \equiv 25\times 5 = 125 \equiv 17 \bmod 36, \quad$ $ 5^4 \equiv 17\times 5 = 85 \equiv 13 \bmod 36, \quad$ $ 5^5 \equiv 13\times 5 = 65 \equiv 29 \bmod 36, \quad$ $ 5^6 \equiv 29\times 5 =  145 \equiv 1 \bmod 36$

Answer (score 0):

You kind-of skip a step in your answer to the first part: noting that $\phi(2^23^2) = \phi(2^2)\phi(3^2) = (1-\frac{1}{2})2^2(1-\frac{1}{3})3^2 =$ etc. The answer is correct of course.

Then, once you know that the maximum order of $5 \bmod 36$ is 12, you also know that the *actual* order divides $12$, so you only need to check $2, 3, 4, 6$ to see if one of those is the order. In this case it doesn't save you much, but you don't (for example) need to check $5^5$:

$\begin{align}
5^2 &= 5\cdot 5 =25\\
5^3 &= 25\cdot 5 = 125 \equiv 17 \bmod 36\\
5^4 &\equiv 17\cdot 5 = 85 \equiv 13 \bmod 36\\
5^6 &\equiv 13\cdot 25 = 325 \equiv 1 \bmod 36 \:\checkmark\\
\end{align}$

Comment: It's slightly more efficient to check the powers $4$ and $6$ first, if both of these are not the identity, the order is $12$. If both are the identity, the order is $2$. If the $6$-th power is the identity, but the $4$-th is not, we check the $3$-rd power (to choose between order $3$ and order $6$), if the $4$-th power is the identity, but the $6$-th is not, the order is $4$. In this particular case, we only save one check-we never have to check the square (which is obvious, anyway).

Comment: @DavidWheeler Yes, I could have gone for the dividing down route too, but since I was calculating out the powers anyway I didn't bother with the extra explanation. It would be an interesting exercise to establish which of bottom-up and top-down are actually more efficient, and when (a priori).

Comment: Lol, yeah, I know how that goes.